# How to read large string from sessionStorage in Blazor WebAssembly? My result is truncated

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I am working on a new Blazor WebAssembly application (NET 5.0) and I'm having trouble reading a large string (~ 3000 characters) from the session storage.  I'm getting a result, but it is truncated with a "..." added to the middle.  The result is always exactly 1000 bytes.

In the code below dataKey is string key of data I want to read.  JSRuntime in injected like this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
```

My first attempt at reading the item from session storage looked like this:

```
// Initial try (truncated)
var myValue1 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", dataKey);
```

Then after doing some searching I saw that it was recommended not to await in a webassembly, so I changed it to this:

```
// Remove the await (still truncated)
var myValue2 = ((IJSInProcessRuntime)JSRuntime).Invoke<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", dataKey);
```

This gave me an identical result, a truncated string of exactly 1000 bytes.

After doing more reading I saw that it was recommended to use an Unmarshalled call for certain cases.  I tried that but my result was only null.  I couldn't find a clear example of this use case, so my code may be incorrect.

```
// Unmarshalled (null)
var myValue3 = ((IJSUnmarshalledRuntime)JSRuntime).InvokeUnmarshalled<string, object>("sessionStorage.getItem", dataKey);
```

After extensive searching I couldn't find any other recommendations.  Can anyone help me read this string from session storage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a page whereon initializing a random value is written into the session storage. When you click a button, the value is read and compared to the expected one. The result is displayed and it is true. I've tested in various browsers.

**However, there is a kind of special behavior here. If you are using the debugger in visual studio** (haven't tested in vs code but assume they behave the same), **you will see only 1000 chars**, even if your string has a lot more of them. In the example just comment the `<p>` tag in to see, that 10,000 chars are displayed but the debugger only shows 1,000.

```
@page "/sessionStorage"
@inject IJSRuntime js

<h1>SessionStorage</h1>

@if (isSame.HasValue == true)
{
  @*<p>@_expectedSessionValue</p>*@
    <p>Result: @isSame</p>
}

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ReadSessionStorage">Click me</button>

@code {
    private Boolean? isSame = null;

    private String _expectedSessionValue = "";
    private String _sessionKey = "key1";


    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Random random = new Random(12345);

        Char[] content = new char[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
        {
            content[i] = (Char)('a' + random.Next(0, 26));
        }

        _expectedSessionValue = new string(content);

        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", new[] { _sessionKey, _expectedSessionValue });

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected async Task ReadSessionStorage()
    {
        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();

        String value = await js.InvokeAsync<String>("sessionStorage.getItem", new[] { _sessionKey });

        isSame = value == _expectedSessionValue;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was using the debugger, so that makes perfect sense.  I printed the text out to the screen and it was the full text I was looking for.  I've never hit this issue on the debugger before, but is definitely something I will be keeping in mind for the future!  Thanks again, I wasted way too much time on this!

Comment: You are welcome It was a very interesting issue. In a first draft, I have written something like, "I couldn't reproduce your bug" but then I watched in the debugger and found it. :)